# Optimizing neo4j queries involving creation of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cartesian-product

I'm interested to create relationships between two nodes having certain properties. The neo4j query for this could be written as:

```
MATCH (x:User {username: "user2064000"}), (y:User {username: "user2064001"}) MERGE (x)-[:KNOWS]->(y)
```

While the query does have the intended effect, the Neo4j web console also warns about the query creating a cartesian product (and about them being slow).

How should I rewrite the above query in order to prevent a cartesian product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a warning, and in your case you don't have to take care about it, because your are doing the following cartesian product :  1 x 1 (I assume that you have a unique constraint on username).

This warning appears when into a MATCH clause you describe two disjoincts patterns.

Cheers.